# fgets() didn't print the first line

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

fgets() not printing the first line of the opened file.
this is the code i have done,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float num;
    char const* const filename=argv[1];
    FILE* file=fopen(filename,"r");
    char line[256];
    int j=0;

    if(file!=NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)!=NULL){
            for(j=0; j<2;j++)
            {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    fscanf(file,"%f",&num);
                    printf("%f \t",num);
                }
                else if(j==1)
                {
                    fscanf(file,"%f",&num);
                    printf("%f \n",num);
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

i get the output as,

```
650.000000  699.000000
99.000000   132.000000
150.000000  272.000000
128.000000  291.000000
302.000000  331.000000
95.000000   199.000000
```

instead of,

```
130.000000   186.000000
650.000000   699.000000
99.000000    132.000000
150.000000   272.000000
128.000000   291.000000
302.000000   331.000000
95.0000000   199.000000
```

I don't get the first line is my problem here. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Format your code properly. `fgets()` never prints anything.

Comment: you've never used `line`.

Comment: That entire `while` loop can be replaced by `while ( fscanf(file, "%f %f", &num1, &num2) == 2 ) { printf("%f\t%f\n", num1, num2); }`

Comment: thnx thnx thnx it works after changing the while loop.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `fgets` reads the first line into `line`, which you never use. Then you proceed to read numbers directly from the file (not from `line`) using `fscanf`. The further calls to `fgets` basically consume the newlines from the file. Try switching `fscanf` to `sscanf` and read from `line` instead of `file`, or alternatively get rid of the `fgets` entirely and exit from the loop based on the return value of `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` doesn't print anything, by definition.   It only reads input.

In any event, your problem is that - each time through the `while` loop, the actions are one call of `fgets()` (the `while` loop condition) followed by two calls of `fscanf()`.  Only the results read using `fscanf()` are output.

The first time through the loop, the data received by the first line of fgets() is simply discarded - so the first line will not be output at all.

On subsequent iterations, the only reason output isn't being skipped is that you're getting lucky.   `fscanf()` - with your format string - stops reading when it encounters a whitespace character, but leaves that character waiting to be read from the file.   If that is a newline character, it will be encountered by the next call of fgets(), which will return immediately (effectively discarding the newline).

The real problem is in how `fgets()` and `fscanf()`, when they are interleaved with each other to read the same file, interact with each other (in this case, because they handle newlines in ways that affect each other in unwanted ways).    The usual guideline, in order to avoid such interactions, is to avoid mixing styles of input on the same file handle  i.e.  don't mix line-oriented input (e.g. `fgets()`) with formatted input (e.g. `fscanf()`) nor with character-oriented input (e.g. `fgetc()`) on the same file handle.

Incidentally, with your code as it stands, you will get even stranger behaviour if you change your input file slightly (e.g. merge two lines into one, add blank lines, etc).   More data will be discarded, but the patterns of what is discarded will be a bit harder to pick.

Comment: thnx a lot for ur time. ive changed the while loop and its working.thnk u guyz